# How to get Label and Value both from system.xml. Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml

I want to get the **value** and **label** both from the **system.xml**
I'm trying

> etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="link" translate="label" type="select"
                sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Link</label>
                <source_model>Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source\Link</source_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="enabled">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>
```

which returns me **dropdown** menu now when I get tried to get value from this function then its only return me the **value** but I also want the **label** as well how can I get both of these values?

Comment: where you want to get value?

Comment: You can set both the same. Otherwise, there is no standard way to get label also.

Comment: actually I'm getting this Link value in Helper n I can get it easily but the issue is I want to get both the Label n Value

Answer (score 1):

Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::getValue` to get the value.

In standard Magento2, you do not have a way to get the label

Comment: I get the values but the issue is I also want to get the label as well

Comment: In standard Magento2, you do not have a way to get the label